# bison and gawk aren't recognized when trying to build

Tags: c, windows, cmake, bison

I'm trying to compile a code I got from github and altered, based on the instructions that github owner provided, part of which include installing Bison and awk.
I installed the two (under different directories: one is C:\Bison and the other is C:\awk) and it seems to have installed without any issues.
However, when I type `cmake ..` in cmd I'm getting the following messages:

```
...
awk not found.  Using previously generated mylib c files in C:/Anaconda2/Whisker
Tracking/generated.
...
-- Could NOT find BISON (missing: BISON_EXECUTABLE)
Bison not found.  Using previously generated parameter parser.
-- Found unsuitable Qt version "5.6.2" from C:/Anaconda2/Library/bin/qmake.exe
...
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Anaconda2/WhiskerTracking/build
```

*I used (...) to cut pieces of the cmd messages that were successful.

Does anyone happen to know why doesn't it recognize bison and awk installed?

Comment: If you type `bison` where you typed `cmake`, does `bison` run?  Ditto for `awk`?  If not, you need to add the install directories to your PATH.  If they are run, you probably need to persuade `cmake` to use your PATH setting.

Comment: they do not run. How do I add them to my PATH?

Comment: just adding the path to the bin directory of each?

Comment: You're on a Windows box.  My current knowledge of Windows is limited (and mostly frustrated).  I'm not sure.  Maybe some variant on `set PATH %PATH%;C:\Awk;C:\Bison` (or maybe add `C:\Awk\bin` etc), but I'd give long odds on that being 100% correct (it will be related, but probably not that — and getting it made permanent is another whole bag'o'worms for which I don't have a good answer).  And if you're using a shell with Unix origins (Bash, etc), you'll use Unix-like notations instead.

Comment: Did you try to use a search engine on "how to add something to the PATH environment variable in windows" or some such query?

Comment: Yeah that's why I added my second comment above.

Comment: did you remember to add the paths for the 'awk' and 'bison' executables to the path list?   With out their being added, how do you expect 'make' to find them?

Comment: both their paths were added

Comment: Have you deleted your build directory and started over?

Comment: I have @usr1234567